# Count total number of Phone Numbers in AddressBook iPhone

Tags: iphone, count, abaddressbook

I am trying to get the total count for the phone numbers listed in the AddressBook, in all groups as a whole.

I can successfully retrieve Person count and Group count, just not the total number of Phone Numbers.

```
ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFIndex nPeople  = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);
CFIndex nGroups  = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(m_addressbook);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);
```

Should return the count for everyone in the address book.

Comment: I think this is what they said they didn't want.

Comment: which I return correctly, need to return the total phone numbers for all persons in all groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
int nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
printf("%d",nPeople);
```